# Data type for protobuf objects in mysql

Tags: mysql, serialization, blob

I would like to store some [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) objects in a MySQL database. The objects are created in a Java application. The object is accompanied with a textual type identifier and a timestamp.

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type       | varchar(30)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| timestamp  | date         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pixel_data | ?            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What should be the datatype of `pixel_data`?

My best guesses are either [`BLOB` or `TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).

- What's the difference between `TEXT` and `BLOB`? Which one is better for Java serialization of `protobuf` objects? Since Java serializes using byte streams, I assume that BLOB is better, but I didn't find any reference for that.
- Assuming that I can only estimate object sizes, which quantifier should I choose (`TINY`, `MEDIUM` or `LONG`)? How much space is wasted for the larger sizes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BLOB` is correct, as that is a binary string. `TEXT` is a character string, but protobuf **is not** character data; so use some kind of `BLOB`

As for `TINY`/`MEDIUM`/`LONG`; how big is your data?

- `TINYBLOB` : max 255 bytes
- `BLOB` : max 65,535 bytes
- `MEDIUMBLOB` : max 16,777,215 bytes
- `LONGBLOB` : max 4,294,967,295 bytes

In some small minority of cases `TINYBLOB` may suffice, especially if there aren't any strings (names/addresses in particular use up space). In most cases, `MEDIUMBLOB` is probably a fair guess.

Comment: +1 Thanks. How much space is wasted for `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLON` when storing small objects?

Comment: @Adam if [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html) is correct, then 1 byte for `TINYBLOB`, 2 bytes for `BLOB`, 3 bytes for `MEDIUMBLOB` and 4 bytes for `LONGBLOB` - I'm not an expert though