# MySQL: Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, collation, utf-8, encoding

I've tried [using a stored procedure to create indices](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24531/mysql-create-index-if-not-exists/24541#24541), and got the following error:

```
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and 
                    (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

There's no line number or any other debugging hint.

- What's the best way to debug this error?
- Are there any good guidelines to avoid encoding inconsistencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trial and error, I've learned how and where to apply `COLLATE`:

Converted lines like:

```sql
SELECT SOMETHING
FROM SOMEWHERE
WHERE table_schema = given_database
AND   table_name   = given_table
AND   index_name   = given_index;
```

To:

```sql
SELECT SOMETHING
FROM SOMEWHERE
WHERE table_schema COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = given_database
AND   table_name   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = given_table
AND   index_name   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = given_index;
```