# jdbc+mysql: "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

Tags: mysql, innodb, jdbc, locking

After recovering from a disk-full problem, I started getting these errors in my logs:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1684)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1108)
    at com.dappit.Dapper.adminer.pixelMaster.storage.RemotePixelStorage.flushBufferToDb(RemotePixelStorage.java:120)
    ...
```

The Java code (`RemotePixelStorage.java:120`):

```
(119) connection.setAutoCommit(false);
(120) int[] returnCodes = pstmt.executeBatch();
(121) connection.setAutoCommit(true);
(122) connection.commit();
```

Each statement is a call to the [stored procedure `add_pixel`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/implementing-a-circular-buffer-sliding-window-in-mysql), which adds an element to a table and removes older elements if necessary.

What does this jdbc exception mean? How can I overcome this issue? Should I simply try to commit a few times with a catch block?

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of the problem, but why does `setAutoCommit(true)` come before `commit()`?

Comment: @dezso - it could have been placed after the commit. If the transaction only contain a single operation there's no reason to turn auto-commit off anyway. This question is using executeBatch so it might contain several statements.

Comment: DISK QUESTION : What disk got full, datadir or /tmp? Are datadir and /tmp on the same mount point? DATA QUESTION : Is the table `pixels` InnoDB ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Stored Procedure, I see something rather unnatural.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `adam_matan`.`AddPixel` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `adam_matan`.`AddPixel`
(
    GivenType VARCHAR(20),
    GivenPixelData BLOB
)
TheStoredProcedure:BEGIN

  DECLARE KeepPixels,DeleteLimit,MaxID INT;

  SET KeepPixels = 5;
  SET DeleteLimit = 100;

  INSERT INTO pixels (type,pixel_data)
  VALUES (GivenType,GivenPixelData);
  SELECT MAX(ID) INTO MaxID FROM pixels;
  IF MOD(MaxID,DeleteLimit) > 0 THEN
      LEAVE TheStoredProcedure;
  END IF;

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pixel_window;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pixel_window
  (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=MyISAM;

  SET @sqlstmt= CONCAT('INSERT INTO pixel_window ',
      'SELECT id FROM pixels WHERE type=''',GivenType,
      ''' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ',KeepPixels);
  PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

  SELECT * FROM pixels WHERE type=GivenType ORDER BY id; SELECT SLEEP(10);
  DELETE A.* FROM pixels A LEFT JOIN pixel_window B USING (id)
  WHERE A.type=GivenType AND B.id IS NULL;
  SELECT * FROM pixels WHERE type=GivenType ORDER BY id;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pixel_window;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The thing I see that is unnatural is the `DELETE ... JOIN` query that is mixing an InnoDB table and a MyISAM table. [Such JOINs tend to be rather clumsy to mysqld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476284/491757).

Let's make the `pixel_window` table. InnoDB. In fact, let's not make it a temporary table. Of course, the hard part is to create a unique `pixel_window` table for the session. The pixel_window temp table will be the prefix 'pixel_window_' with the Connection ID appended.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `adam_matan`.`AddPixel` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `adam_matan`.`AddPixel`
(
    GivenType VARCHAR(20),
    GivenPixelData BLOB
)
TheStoredProcedure:BEGIN

  DECLARE KeepPixels,DeleteLimit,MaxID INT;

  SET KeepPixels = 5;
  SET DeleteLimit = 100;

  INSERT INTO pixels (type,pixel_data)
  VALUES (GivenType,GivenPixelData);
  SELECT MAX(ID) INTO MaxID FROM pixels;
  IF MOD(MaxID,DeleteLimit) > 0 THEN
      LEAVE TheStoredProcedure;
  END IF;

  SET @pwtable = CONCAT('pixel_window_',CONNECTION_ID());

  #
  # Create the pixel_window Table
  #
  SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',pwtable,' (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB');
  PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

  #
  # Load the pixel_window Table
  #
  SET @sqlstmt= CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@pwtable,' ',
      'SELECT id FROM pixels WHERE type=''',GivenType,
      ''' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ',KeepPixels);
  PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

  SELECT * FROM pixels WHERE type=GivenType ORDER BY id; SELECT SLEEP(10);

  #
  # Use the pixel_window Table to perform DELETE...JOIN
  #
  SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('DELETE A.* FROM pixels A LEFT JOIN ',
  @pwtable,' B USING (id) WHERE A.type=GivenType AND B.id IS NULL');
  PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

  SELECT * FROM pixels WHERE type=GivenType ORDER BY id;

  #
  # Drop the pixel_window Table
  #
  SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',@pwtable);
  PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt; EXECUTE st; DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT : Since I created this monster, I needed to slay it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You say you just recovered from a 'disk full' condition.
You also never said what other processes/programs access this data.
We need an enumeration of other accessing programs because they could be the source of the **deadlock**.

Remember **deadlock** means *competing access* especially for writing.
Now ... consider your **ACID** qualities: **Atomicity, Consistency, Durability & Isolation** ....